# First- and second-differences in `marginaleffects`

Tags: r, regression, probability, marginal-effects, r-marginaleffects

I would like to compute so-called first- and second- differences (as defined e.g. [here](https://sociologicalscience.com/articles-v6-4-81/)) with the package `marginaleffects`, with standard errors, but I am not sure which function I can use.

Consider this example model:

```r
library(marginaleffects)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp * factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
pred <- predictions(mod, newdata = datagrid(cyl = levels(factor(mtcars$cyl)),
                                            hp = seq(80, 110, 10)))

#    rowid     type predicted std.error statistic       p.value conf.low conf.high cyl  hp mpg
# 1      1 response  26.96095 0.9210528 29.271888 2.364796e-188 25.06770  28.85421   4  80  21
# 2      2 response  25.83320 0.9732779 26.542467 3.137628e-155 23.83259  27.83380   4  90  21
# 3      3 response  24.70544 1.2102719 20.413129  1.278321e-92 22.21769  27.19319   4 100  21
# 4      4 response  23.57768 1.5494525 15.216780  2.736718e-52 20.39273  26.76262   4 110  21
# 5      5 response  20.06479 2.4401222  8.222863  1.987022e-16 15.04905  25.08053   6  80  21
# 6      6 response  19.98866 2.0043577  9.972599  2.009006e-23 15.86864  24.10867   6  90  21
# 7      7 response  19.91252 1.6124942 12.348897  4.938402e-35 16.59799  23.22705   6 100  21
# 8      8 response  19.83639 1.3047065 15.203720  3.340987e-52 17.15453  22.51825   6 110  21
# 9      9 response  16.94054 2.2777361  7.437448  1.026490e-13 12.25859  21.62250   8  80  21
# 10    10 response  16.79810 2.1245264  7.906752  2.641918e-15 12.43108  21.16513   8  90  21
# 11    11 response  16.65566 1.9731806  8.441022  3.145744e-17 12.59973  20.71159   8 100  21
# 12    12 response  16.51322 1.8241629  9.052492  1.397416e-19 12.76360  20.26284   8 110  21
```

Given the `pred` dataframe, how can one estimate

1. **First difference.** The difference between each contrasting value, for instance between `cyl == 8` and `cyl == 4` for each of the `hp` values, with a similar output than in `pred` (e.g. with p.value, std.error...)?
2. **Second difference.** The difference between those differences, i.e. for each of the differences computed in the first step, the difference between them as well as the standard errors.

I am looking for a method that could hopefully work also for logistic regression.

Comment: Maybe you can mess around with the `?contrasts`, not sure how, though. Or `multcomp::glht`, see: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-test-contrasts-in-r/

Comment: Good tips. Although I've been trying to mess around with `contrasts`, I am a bit confused what is the go-to way.

Comment: Rose's tutorial comes to mind: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/65059_586f394d8eb84f84b1baaf56ffb6b47f.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First differences

The `comparisons()` function gives first differences. You will find a very detailed tutorial in this vignette: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/contrasts.html

```r
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp * factor(cyl), data = mtcars)

comparisons(
    mod,
    variables = "cyl",
    by = "hp",
    newdata = datagrid(cyl = unique, hp = seq(80, 110, 10))) |>
    summary()
#>   Term          Contrast  hp  Effect Std. Error z value   Pr(>|z|)   2.5 %
#> 1  cyl mean(6) - mean(4)  80  -6.896      2.608  -2.644 0.00819167 -12.008
#> 2  cyl mean(6) - mean(4)  90  -5.845      2.228  -2.623 0.00871522 -10.212
#> 3  cyl mean(6) - mean(4) 100  -4.793      2.016  -2.377 0.01744227  -8.745
#> 4  cyl mean(6) - mean(4) 110  -3.741      2.026  -1.847 0.06474713  -7.711
#> 5  cyl mean(8) - mean(4)  80 -10.020      2.457  -4.078 4.5336e-05 -14.836
#> 6  cyl mean(8) - mean(4)  90  -9.035      2.337  -3.866 0.00011048 -13.615
#> 7  cyl mean(8) - mean(4) 100  -8.050      2.315  -3.478 0.00050600 -12.587
#> 8  cyl mean(8) - mean(4) 110  -7.064      2.393  -2.952 0.00316093 -11.755
#> 
#> Model type:  lm 
#> Prediction type:  response
```

#### Second differences

You can take differences in differences using the `hypothesis` argument. You will find a very detailed tutorial in this vignette: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/hypothesis.html

```r
comparisons(
    mod,
    variables = "cyl",
    by = "hp",
    hypothesis = "pairwise",
    newdata = datagrid(cyl = unique, hp = seq(80, 110, 10))) |>
    summary()
#>                                             Term  Effect Std. Error  z value
#> 1  mean(6) - mean(4), 80 - mean(6) - mean(4), 90 -1.0516     0.6848 -1.53560
#> 2  mean(6) - mean(4), 80 - mean(6) - mean(4),100 -2.1033     1.3697 -1.53560
#> 3  mean(6) - mean(4), 80 - mean(6) - mean(4),110 -3.1549     2.0545 -1.53560
#> 4  mean(6) - mean(4), 80 - mean(8) - mean(4), 80  3.1242     3.3380  0.93596
#> 5  mean(6) - mean(4), 80 - mean(8) - mean(4), 90  2.1389     3.2676  0.65459
#> 6  mean(6) - mean(4), 80 - mean(8) - mean(4),100  1.1536     3.2688  0.35292
#> 7  mean(6) - mean(4), 80 - mean(8) - mean(4),110  0.1683     3.3414  0.05037
#> 8  mean(6) - mean(4), 90 - mean(6) - mean(4),100 -1.0516     0.6848 -1.53560
#> 9  mean(6) - mean(4), 90 - mean(6) - mean(4),110 -2.1033     1.3697 -1.53560
#> 10 mean(6) - mean(4), 90 - mean(8) - mean(4), 80  4.1759     3.0684  1.36095
#> 11 mean(6) - mean(4), 90 - mean(8) - mean(4), 90  3.1906     2.9208  1.09236
#> 12 mean(6) - mean(4), 90 - mean(8) - mean(4),100  2.2052     2.8496  0.77388
#> 13 mean(6) - mean(4), 90 - mean(8) - mean(4),110  1.2199     2.8604  0.42648
#> 14 mean(6) - mean(4),100 - mean(6) - mean(4),110 -1.0516     0.6848 -1.53560
#> 15 mean(6) - mean(4),100 - mean(8) - mean(4), 80  5.2275     2.9369  1.77994
#> 16 mean(6) - mean(4),100 - mean(8) - mean(4), 90  4.2422     2.7061  1.56763
#> 17 mean(6) - mean(4),100 - mean(8) - mean(4),100  3.2569     2.5483  1.27808
#> 18 mean(6) - mean(4),100 - mean(8) - mean(4),110  2.2715     2.4773  0.91695
#> 19 mean(6) - mean(4),110 - mean(8) - mean(4), 80  6.2791     2.9621  2.11984
#> 20 mean(6) - mean(4),110 - mean(8) - mean(4), 90  5.2938     2.6557  1.99334
#> 21 mean(6) - mean(4),110 - mean(8) - mean(4),100  4.3085     2.4094  1.78824
#> 22 mean(6) - mean(4),110 - mean(8) - mean(4),110  3.3232     2.2427  1.48175
#> 23 mean(8) - mean(4), 80 - mean(8) - mean(4), 90 -0.9853     0.4862 -2.02641
#> 24 mean(8) - mean(4), 80 - mean(8) - mean(4),100 -1.9706     0.9725 -2.02641
#> 25 mean(8) - mean(4), 80 - mean(8) - mean(4),110 -2.9560     1.4587 -2.02641
#> 26 mean(8) - mean(4), 90 - mean(8) - mean(4),100 -0.9853     0.4862 -2.02641
#> 27 mean(8) - mean(4), 90 - mean(8) - mean(4),110 -1.9706     0.9725 -2.02641
#> 28 mean(8) - mean(4),100 - mean(8) - mean(4),110 -0.9853     0.4862 -2.02641
#> 
#> Model type:  lm 
#> Prediction type:  response
```